# WSO2 Publisher: use endpoint {service-IP}:{port} instead of localhost:{port}

Tags: kubernetes, wso2, wso2-api-manager, api-gateway

I was deploying an integration solution using Integration Studio, after deploying it to my kubernetes cluster the service appeared fine in my services list in the publisher.

**Problem**: after creating an API from that service, the endpoint ends up being **localhost:{port}**, of course this endpoint doesn't work when using the gateway since it must be **{service IP of integration}:{port}**

Do I have to manually change the endpoint every time ? I want to know if there's something I can do to make this process easier

here's my metadata.yaml folder

```
serviceUrl: "https://{MI_HOST}:{MI_PORT}/mock"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 2):

If you need to parameterize the serviceUrl in the metadata file, you must inject the parameterized values as environment variables in the MI instance.

Refer the point 5 in step 4 in here - https://apim.docs.wso2.com/en/latest/tutorials/develop-an-integration-with-a-managed-api/#step-4-configure-the-micro-integrator

Comment: I understand, do you have any idea how I can obtain the service IP automatically once it's deployed to my cluster and injecting it ?

Comment: If you are deploying in K8s, you can use the K8s service name. IP can be changed anytime and best option is to use the K8s service name.